# uniformly convergence of $f_{n}(x)=\frac{n}{2}\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} f(t)dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f:[-1,2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Define a function sequences:
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{n}(x)=\frac{n}{2}\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}} f(t)dt
\end{eqnarray*}
for all $x\in [0,1]$ and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Show that $(f_{n})$ converges to $f$ uniformly in $[0,1]$.

---

My work:

By hypotesis $f$ is continuous in $[-1,2]$ so, By first theorem of  first fundamental theorem of calculus $f'_{n}$ exist and :
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'_{n}=\frac{n}{2}(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x-\frac{1}{n}))
\end{eqnarray*}
so in this case $x\in[0,1]$ and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

So I think to analysis the uniformly convergence by differential theorem and study:
\begin{eqnarray*}
|f'_{n}(x)-f'(x)|&=&|\frac{n}{2}(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x-\frac{1}{n}))-f'(x)|
\end{eqnarray*}
But I don't know if exist some point $x_{0}\in(0,1)$ such that $(f_{n}(x_{0}))$ converges and if $f'(x)$ exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left|\frac{n}{2}\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n}\left(f(t)-f(x)\right)dt\right| \le \frac{n}{2}\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n}|f(x)-f(t)|dt$$

Now you can use that $f$ is uniform continuous on $[-1,2]$ to finish.

Comment: Do you say that $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=|\frac{n}{2}(\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}(f(t)-f(x))dt)|$?

Comment: It's the same I wrote